How to Connect TinaCMS to MongoDB in Next.js Project
I’m working on a Next.js project where I’m trying to integrate TinaCMS with MongoDB. I’m having trouble getting TinaCMS to connect to my MongoDB database. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Next.js Setup:
I created a new Next.js project and installed TinaCMS and the required dependencies.
TinaCMS Configuration:
I have a config.js file with basic configuration, but I’m not sure how to fully integrate TinaCMS with MongoDB.
From the official TinaCMS documentation, I found a code snippet that uses the MongodbLevel adapter:
import { MongodbLevel } from 'mongodb-level';

// ...

export default isLocal
  ? createLocalDatabase()
  : createDatabase({
      // ...
      databaseAdapter: new MongodbLevel<string, Record<string, any>>({
        // If you are not using branches you could pass a static collection name. ie: "tinacms"
        collectionName: `tinacms-${branchName}`,
        dbName: 'tinacms',
        mongoUri: process.env.MONGODB_URI as string,
      }),
    });



Got my solution here https://github.com/tinacms/tina-self-hosted-gc-demo/blob/main/tina/config.tsx
